# nth-child among hidden children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a number of elements (siblings) which may or may not be hidden (have the class "is-hidden" applied to it).

I want to select one of the elements based on its index, thus using the :nth-child pseudo class.

However, I want to select the nth *visible* child, not the nth child of all elements. So I tried something like:

```
$('.product-cell'):not('is-hidden'):nth-child(2);
```

But that doesn't work, have I messed up my syntax or is it impossible to stack pseudo classes like this? How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Excuse me, very tired this afternoon. So much that I can't tell jQuery from CSS :) Problem resolved using jQuery and rebuilding other parts of my solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But that doesn't work, have I messed up my syntax or is it impossible to stack pseudo classes like this? How do I go about solving this problem?

Both, actually.

If you're using the colon syntax you need to put all your selectors in a single string. If you want to use multiple method calls, it's with a period `.` instead of a colon `:`.

Additionally, `:nth-child()` always picks an element that's the nth child of its parent, regardless of whether it's hidden or has a certain class, etc. So you need to use `:eq()` instead of `:nth-child()`, like this:

```
// :eq() is zero-indexed so :eq(1) selects the second match
$('.product-cell:not(.is-hidden):eq(1)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you're missing the class selector in your `not` statement however the `not()` and `nth-child()` selectors in jQuery are designed to be part of your initial selector.

```
$('.product-cell:not(.is-hidden):nth-child(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understand is correct,

You are looking for the `nth child` which doesn't have a class called `.is-hidden` that is nothing but last child of the not `.is-hidden` class.

Assuming that your HTML looks like this:-

```
<ul class='product-cell'> 
    <li>Glen</li> 
    <li class='is-hidden'>Tane</li> 
    <li>Ralph</li>
    <li class='is-hidden'>David</li>
    <li class='is-hidden'>David111</li>
    <li>David22</li>
</ul>
```

To get the last child, below is the JQuery

```
$('.product-cell li[not(.is-hidden)]:last-child').text()
```

## Result:

```
David22
```